# which one first happened? "dragging the canal" or "ordering to enter the canal"?

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

which one first happened? "dragging the canal" or "ordering to enter the canal"?

> The danger of blindly following alleged spirit guidance was clearly
>   shown some months later in the neighbouring town of Rochester, where a
>   man disappeared under suspicious circumstances. An enthusiastic
>   Spiritualist had messages by raps which announced a murder. **The canal
>   was dragged and the wife of the missing man was actually ordered to
>   enter the canal, which nearly cost her her life**. Some months later the
>   absentee returned, having fled to Canada to avoid a writ for debt.
>   This, as may well be imagined, was a blow to the young cult. The
>   public did not then understand what even now is so little understood,
>   that death causes no change in the human spirit, that mischievous and
>   humorous entities abound, and that the inquirer must use his own
>   instincts and his own common sense at every turn.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: Google it, or look at: https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/248478-drag-the-canal

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "dragged" is similar to "dredged" - the process of clearing the bed of a harbour, river, or other area of water by scooping out mud, weeds, and rubbish with a dredge. However in your example, the process is for the purpose of searching for something rather than cleaning.